# Xamarin, Android: Animation is a little laggy (using Timers)

Tags: android, timer

I am trying to animate my ImageView from the XML. It is basically moving from the center positino to the top of the screen. Do achieve this, I used a timer that fires a function every x miliseconds. This function then moves the object a littler further up. It does work, but it is laggy. I am debugging on a Samsung S7, so power should not be an issue. I guess the timer is just very inaccurate. Can you show me a better way of doing it instead of this:

```
 public class finalPhoto : Activity
    {
        private System.Timers.Timer timer;
        private ImageView wowThatLooksFantastic;
        private float i = 0f;
        private int test = 0; 
        private int NegativeSpeed = 350; 
        private int frameRate = 17; // 17 = etwa 60fps

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.finalPhoto);

            wowThatLooksFantastic = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.text_wowthatlooksfantastic);

            wowThatLooksFantastic.Click += delegate { StartAnimation(); };

            test = Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels; 


        }
    private void StartAnimation()
    {
        i = wowThatLooksFantastic.GetY();
        CountDown(); 
    }

    public void CountDown()
    {

        timer = new System.Timers.Timer();
        timer.Interval = frameRate;
        timer.Elapsed += OnTimedEvent;
        timer.Start(); 

    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
    }


    public void OnTimedEvent(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        i -= (test/NegativeSpeed); 
        wowThatLooksFantastic.SetY(i);

        if (wowThatLooksFantastic.GetY() <= 50) // Endposition
        {
            timer.Stop(); 
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why all that code, just define in Resources/drawable XML file file this for example move_up.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
    android:fillAfter="true">

    <translate
        android:fromYDelta="50%p"
        android:toYDelta="0%p"
        android:duration="1000" />
</set>
```

This means that it will start from the center of Y position of screen and go to the top. In duration you put how much milliseconds you want that to move.
And than just to your imageView add this

```
   Animation anim2 = AnimationUtils.LoadAnimation(this.BaseContext, Resource.Drawable.move_up);
   ImageView myImage = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
   myImage.StartAnimation(anim2);
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a shot next week! I will report back! :)

Comment: Hope this helps, write if you have more questions :)

Comment: This works brilliantly. My tip: Use this interpolator: android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_decelerate_interpolator" it will make the animations look a lot more fluent!

Comment: Thanks will try with that one